# What kind of files are these? Compiled files, self extracting files or something else?

Tags: linux, compile, self-extracting

I'm a newbie using Linux. I understand that there are binary packages a source code that may come in .zip. However, I downloaded a zip package (you can see in the picture). I just extracted, then cd into bin and run "autopsy".

Is this a self-extracting file? Is this a compiled file? Are self-extracting files, compiled files? I used "extract to" to extract the file no other software was used, which makes the file self-extractable?

[image]
[image]

Comment: MSI is a Windows format. Did you get the "autopsy" package for your distribution of Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Those are Windows executables, not Linux binaries.

I'd advise you to steer away from Kali. It's not a desktop distro in the first place. It's a special toolset created for security professionals. It's missing a lot of things which desktop distros provide out of the box, as they are not needed for the purpose. Considering your level of knowledge you're only asking for headaches. Just for example you don't recognize Windows exe files, you don't know they don't run on Linux and you think source code is delivered as binaries...

You should install a more approachable Linux distro and learn how Linux works first. Ubuntu and Mint are very popular, Zorin is specially targeted for people moving from Windows to Linux, very easy to grasp. That's how you learn your way around. If you want to learn about Kali, you can run it as a Virtual Machine. That's how most professionals use it anyway. And all three I mentioned are Debian-based, just like Kali - so knowing how to use them makes using Kali easier.

If you want to learn the tools you don't even need Kali. The tools are open source, available for any Linux.

Comment: I downloaded autopsy-4.19.1.zip on Kali Linux and it worked. So I guessed this are called compiled files, self extracting files?  I just want to know the terminology. If it was a windows executables why it worked on kali linux

Comment: Autopsy 4 is what I gave in my answer to you. Likely the Windows MSI was just ignored.

Comment: .zip file works because it's a universal compression format. To unpack it on any OS you just need a tool that can uncompress .zip files. .exe files are Win binaries. Linux has its own binaries, but the same as any UNIX-like OS they are not denoted with a specific file extension. Different Linux distros have also different binaries; I can't just download a RedHat binary and run it on my Debian. "Compiled files" isn't a term in general use; all binary files are compiled from source code to run on a specific target OS. They cannot run on a different OS without using an emulator or similar tool.

Comment: To add a bit; self-extracting file under Windows also has file extension .exe. This is because it's also an executable. When you execute it, it unpacks a compressed file it contains. So just by looking at file `foo.exe` it's not possible to determine what its function is; it could as well launch application `foo` as unpack its contents to directory `foo`. Under UNIX, Linux or MacOS it's generally impossible to identify a file by name. File named `foo` could be an application, a picture, a text file, an audio file... or a pipe... or a device... anything.

Answer (score 0):

Autopsy comes in Windows and Linux versions. I think you downloaded the Windows version.

[Autopsy download](https://www.autopsy.com/download/)

Autopsy 4 will run on Linux and OS X. To do so:

> Download the Autopsy ZIP file Linux will need The Sleuth Kit Java .deb
> Debian package Follow the instructions to install other dependencies

Notice Autopsy is for Debian (and likely Ubuntu). Also notice the need to install dependencies.

You can try here [Kali[2](https://www.kali.org/tools/autopsy/) for a Kali version (I have not tried it)

(Posted from my Kali 2021.3 machine).

Comment: According to Kali documentation there's no need to dowload, it installs with apt.